# How to convert Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, int>>>> to json

Tags: json, flutter, dart

So I have this data :

```
{
  2021: {
    01: {
      4: {2: 3},
      5: {2: 3},
      6: {2: 3},
      ...
    },
  },
  2022: {
    01: {
      4: {2: 3},
      5: {2: 3},
      6: {2: 3},
      ...
    },
  },
}
```

which is a `Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, int>>>>`

The purpose of this structure is to hold information abount every day of a years calendar week like this:

```
    {
      year: {
        calendarweek: {
          day: {2 out of 3},
          day: {2 out of 3},
          ...
        },
      },
      year: {
        calendarweek: {
          day: {2 out of 3},
          day: {2 out of 3},
          ...
        },
      },
    }
```

Now I want to store this information as Json but the conversion is giving me a REALLY hard time.

So how would I de- and encode this data from/to json?

Comment: this is not a valid JSON - what do you want to do with such poor json?

Comment: I know that this is not a JSON, its a Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, int>>>>.
My question was how I would convert this structure to JSON.

Comment: so what is the second snippet you posted? the one with `day: {2 out of 3}`? is it a final string you want to get?

Comment: the second snippet was just for expanation what the numbers stand for. the `day: {2 out of 3}` just meant that the key in this case is a 2 and the value a 3. 

Sorry thats a bit misleading.

Comment: Actually, I am just thinking maybe I should create an entire new Class for this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed to encode your data to Json format, the keys should be String objects otherwise you get error messages, my example:

```
import 'dart:convert';

const data = {
  '2021': {
    '01': {
      '4': {'2': 3},
      '5': {'2': 3},
      '6': {'2': 3},
    },
  },
  '2022': {
    '01': {
      '4': {'2': 3},
      '5': {'2': 3},
      '6': {'2': 3},
    },
  },
};

void main(List<String> args) {
  var myData = jsonEncode(data);
  // var myData = jsonEncode({'2':3});

  print(myData.runtimeType);
  print(myData);
}
```

Result:

```
String
{"2021":{"01":{"4":{"2":3},"5":{"2":3},"6":{"2":3}}},"2022":{"01":{"4":{"2":3},"5":{"2":3},"6":{"2":3}}}}
```